# cascading drop down in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am a newbie to Zend Framework and I am trying to making a Form using Zend Form. In that Form I want cascading drop downs of country, state and city. I have filled country's drop down from database but I have no idea how do I fill state's drop down by getting the country id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To dynamically load countries you should use it the way you did:

> I have done this previously with standard php and jquery

And here is nothing to do with `Zend_Form`. You should have a `JSON` service (for e.g.) that will accept `CountryID` and will return all states available.

For this purpose you should connect `jQuery` library in your `<head>` section.

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.7.3.js'); // In your Controller
```

Add you `jQuery` script to your `template` which will handle all events like this:

```
$_form->inlineScript()->appendScript(' // my raw JS here');
```

or

```
$_form->inlineScript()->appendFile('js/dynamicCountry.js'); // if you want to keep it in separate file
```

And here you are, nothing to do with `Zend_From` except assigning correct elements `ID`'s, `classes` or `names`.

And for your `service` you can do smth. similar. Suppose URL `http://localhost/mysite/service/states/country/AT`

```
/**
 * In your Service controller disable rendering for your layout and views
 */
public function preDispatch() {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); // if you have `layout` enabled
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
```

and ... welcome

```
public function statesAction() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    /**
     * Country code transmitted through the parameter
     * @var string
     */
    $country = $request->getParam('country');

        // you are free to do whatever you want and return JSON (for e.g.)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an associative array like this :

```
$tCountries = array(
    1 => "France",
    2 => "USA"
);

$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select();
$element->addMultiOptions($tCountries);
```

You could find more informations here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select

Comment: Thanks for replying but I have already done this. I have filled country's drop down with value and key that is coming from database in an array. This is not my problem. My problem is when a user select country then state's drop down should filled with the available state in that country automatically. I have done this previously with standard php and jquery. But here I want to do it in Zend_Form.

Comment: What do you do when you receive the form ?

Comment: When that form load, Country's drop down will have all country name that is in database and other drop down like state and city will not any value right now. When user select country then I want state's drop down should be filled with state's that are in that country and same for city drop down.